# String Variable is not carrying over to OnGUI() Label

Tags: c#

I am creating a program that reads an external text file after my unity project has been built. The Debug log can read the external file perfectly and send back my text or detect when no file is present - my only problem is transferring the txt variable into a GUI label? I was wondering why the String variable is not being passed correctly as it just shows nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void Start () {
    StreamReader reader = null;
    FileInfo theSourceFile = null;

    theSourceFile = new FileInfo (Application.dataPath + "/puzzles.txt");
    if ( theSourceFile != null && theSourceFile.Exists )
        reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();

    if ( reader == null )
    {
        Debug.Log("puzzles.txt not found or not readable");
    }
    else
    {
        // Read each line from the file
        while ((txt = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            Debug.Log("-->" + txt);
    }
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
    GUI.Label(new Rect(500, 300, 400, 400), txt );
}
```

Comment: Also to add - The txt variable is public already

Comment: Well, givent hat your Start() fires first, then your OnGUI(), the while loop in Start() will set text to null in order to terminate. Hence null will be passed into label call. Simply put a Debug.Log(txt) call inside your OnGUI() function. P.S.S. search for how to use breakpoints in debugger.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help Nicko! Okay, I did have the OnGUI() Method call as well earlier but that did not work either? What should I do then to stop null being passed into the label call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how the code above is working. It looks like you expect the code above to show the lines of the text file until it's read completly, however the `Start()` method finishes before any call of the `OnGUI()` method.

Means that the last call of `txt = reader.ReadLine()` is null and so `OnGUI` shows nothing.

If you want to show the text above i suggest to add another variable and put the string content into the secondary variable ( `txt` don't require to be a class variable in this case ).

Small sample which could be faster by using a `StringBuilder`:

```
String txt;
completeText = "";
while ((txt = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Debug.Log(....);
    completeText += txt;
}
```

And in your `OnGUI` method:

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(500, 300, 400, 400), completeText );
```

If you want, for whatever reason, to show each line seperatly i suggest to use a coroutine with a delay between each `ReadLine`.

Comment: You sir are an absolute Legend! That worked for me after I added the completeText += txt! I should have put abit more thought into the Methods themselves as in  how Start() functions, but I could not have done that without you! Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: Sorry to be an annoyance but for reading between lines could you provide any more help on that? So reading the text file line by line? I tried to research coroutines and used this.

private IEnumerator seperateText()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        }

But it would cut off lines or only display one line?

Thank you

Comment: Basically you start a coroutine and put into the while a `WaitForSeconds` and assign the text like you did before but using txt in your label function again.